# Push plugin issue while one application open from another

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have two Cordova application.app2 has push plugin installed and app2 is opened from app1 using data scheme(not directly launch).when the application is in background ,notification does not directed to related application.